# how to send an Id to controller by Button in asp.net mvc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, model-view-controller, controller, ef-code-first

I have a table and end of their record is Buy Button.
how can I send an Id of product in foreach to controller.

```
@foreach(var model in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>@model.Title</td>
       <td>@model.Counts</td>
       <td>@model.Price</td>
       <td> <button class="btn btn-warning">Buy</button> </td>
   </tr> 
}
```

Comment: Typically you'd drop in a hidden field that holds the ID.  Is this for loop inside a form?

Comment: @NathanChampion no there is no form

Comment: The easiest approach is probably to convert the button to a bootstrap link button and pass the ID via the link.  Something like <a href="/Buy?id=@model.id" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">Buy</a>

Comment: @NathanChampion yeah that’s a good idea. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either [`@Html.ActionLink()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) or HTML anchor tag with [`@Url.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_Action_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) helper to send the `Id` property of the model and style it to look like a button:

**Anchor tag version**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Buy", "ControllerName", new { id = model.Id })" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">Buy</a>
```

**ActionLink helper version**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Buy", "Buy", "ControllerName", new { id = model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning", @role = "button" })
```

Both methods will produce same result (`X` refers to passed ID value):

```
<a href="/ControllerName/Buy?id=X" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">Buy</a>
```